# Helper Gem for Rest on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, rubygems

I know that Rails has some tools on board to create a REST API. However, concepts like HATEOS aren't supported out of the box.

I googled around for Gems that are filling the gap. The most complete Gem I found is Restfulie (https://github.com/caelum/restfulie). But I am not complete convinced about Restfulie and the project looks abandoned. Hence, I am looking for good alternatives to Restfulie.

What's the best Gem to create a REST API for Rails?

Answer (score 3):

Popular choices are [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) and [Roar](https://github.com/apotonick/roar) / [roar-rails](https://github.com/apotonick/roar-rails).

I personally like Roar better because it allows you to consume your representations which is a bit harder with RABL. On the other hand, it's concepts are still in flux so things still tend to change.

Answer (score 2):

[Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) is worth a try.